# How to compare multiple table columns with multiple values?

Tags: mysql, performance, select, where-clause

I have a table with **N** columns like this

---

> column 1 | column 2 | column 3 | ...column **N**

---

I have **n** values like this

---

> value 1 , value 2 , value 3 , ...value **n**

---

I wanted to compare these **n** values with my table's **N** columns. One way I can do it is:

```
Select * from table where

column 1 IN (value 1 , value 2 , value 3 , ...value n)
||
column 2 IN (value 1 , value 2 , value 3 , ...value n)
||
column 3 IN (value 1 , value 2 , value 3 , ...value n)
||
.
.
.
column n IN (value1 , value1 , value1 , ...value n)
```

Is this the most ***fastest*** way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case no.

i would suggest to change structure of the database if it's possible:

table
id | column | value_of_column |

date example:

```
1 | column_1 |  zzz
2 | colums_2 | yyyy
3 | colums_1 | yyyy
4 | colums_5 | yyyy
....
```

and then your query:

```
select * from table where value_of_column in (value......)
```